# Different line spacings for main text and footnotes in beamer

Tags: beamer, footnotes, line-spacing

In my `beamer` presentation, I want

- the main text to have a line spacing of 1.5,
- footnotes to have a line spacing of 1, both *within* them and *between* two consecutive footnotes.

Inserting `\linespread{1.5}` in the document's scope results in a line spacing of 1.5 in *both* main text and footnotes, which is undesirable.

I know that, generally, the preferred way of achieving the desired output is to load the `setspace` package and insert `\setstretch{1.5}` somewhere in the document's scope, but loading `setspace` seems to break `beamer`'s `\footnote`. For instance, the following MWE does not produce any footnote:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
foo\footnote{bar}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A workaround is to entirely eschew the `setspace` package and use `\linespread` to locally change the line spacing in footnotes, like so:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand\footnote[2][]{{\linespread{1}\oldfootnote[#1]{#2}}}
\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
foo\footnote{\lipsum[2]}\\
bar\footnote{sdfsdf}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which produces the desired line spacing (1) *within* footnotes, but not *between* them:

[image]

What should I do to produce the desired output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a design feature. T. Tantau defends the opinion that there should not be a footnote on a slide. Stuff that is not inline with his view is usually difficult to do in beamer and many macros are overwritten accordingly. To be honest I agree with him after suffering from undescribable pain in many conferences. Funny thing is that most people are driving `beamer` to act like PowerPoint which is interesting to see.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setbeamertemplate{footnote}%
{%
  \parindent 1em\noindent%
  \raggedright\setstretch{1}%
  \hbox to 1.8em{\hfil\insertfootnotemark}\insertfootnotetext\par%
}

\begin{document}
\setstretch{1.5}
\begin{frame}

foo\footnote[frame]{bar}\par
foobar

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
foo\footnote{bar}

bar\footnote[frame]{Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, 
wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, 
ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula 
aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.}
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with you and Till Tantau, but I thing footnotes can still be useful in presentations, as long as they are used sparingly (for links, etc.).

Comment: @Jubobs My pleasure. Don't get me wrong, it's just my opinionated view on it. Otherwise bring it on :)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not work for me at all, as all my footnotes kept disappearing as soon as I used the `setspace` package. I managed to get a simpler solution by combining this answer and [footfullcite not working when package setspace is present](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234847/footfullcite-not-working-when-package-setspace-is-present)

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\setbeamertemplate{footnote}%
{%
  \parindent 1em\noindent%
  \raggedright\linespread{1}\selectfont%
  \hbox to 1.8em{\hfil\insertfootnotemark}\insertfootnotetext\par%
}

\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

foo\footnote[frame]{bar}\par
foobar
\vspace{2cm}

\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
foo\footnote{bar}

bar\footnote[frame]{Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, 
wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, 
ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula 
aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.}
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is it possible to have a complete compilable example and why have you written "The accepted answer did not work for me at all, as all my footnotes kept disappering..": Please, do you explain better your answer?

Comment: Hey, I have updated the answer to a full working script (basically a copy-paste from the accepted answer with my modifications). 
As to what I mean by  "all my footnotes kept disappearing as soon as I used the setspace package" I mean exactly that: They just vanished. Not in this simple example but with the beamer template I used.

Comment: @Joschua It's strange that you got this behaviour, especially since the accepted answer clearly does work. It might be more useful to others if you constructed a non-working example with `setspace` and used that to ask a new question rather than posting this answer with a vague reference to things not working.