# footfullcite not working when package setspace is present

Tags: beamer, footnotes, setspace

for my beamer presentation, I am using `footfullcite`.
This is working fine, unless I also use `setspace`.

Attached is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{mini}
  \usepackage[
    backend=bibtex8,
  ]{biblatex}          
  \usepackage{setspace}
\addbibresource{mini.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{Start}
\begin{frame}
  %\setstretch{2}              
Some text \footfullcite{keys}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

with mini.bib:

```
@article{keys,
  author={Author},
  title={Title}
}
```

The cite count is coming, but not the bibliography.[image].

What I am looking for is citation at the bottom of each slide, with double spacing between line, like:
[image]

with `\setstretch{2}`

Comment: This problem is by no means `biblatex`-specififc and also appears if one uses any other `\footnote` commands. So I decided to slightly re-tag your question to reflect this.

Comment: @egreg: no....thats not the case. you can just \usepackage{setspace} without **actually** using it....and it is still not visible

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `setspace` package redefines `\@footnotetext` so that it doesn't use normal baselineskip; however the definition it assumes is the one in the LaTeX kernel, but `beamer` has a *very* different definition for `\@footnotetext`.

Since the new definition provided by `setspace` is something `beamer` can do nothing with, because the footnote text is saved in a different `\insert` class than the one used by `beamer`, the footnotes simply disappear in hyperspace.

Here's a patch:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% save the meaning of \@footnotetext
\let\BEAMER@footnotetext\@footnotetext
\makeatother

\usepackage{setspace}

\makeatletter
% restore the meaning of \@footnotetext
\let\@footnotetext\BEAMER@footnotetext
% patch the relevant command to do single spacing in footnotes
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname beamerx@\string\beamer@framefootnotetext\endcsname
  {\reset@font}
  {\def\baselinestretch{\setspace@singlespace}\reset@font}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
TEXT\footnote{FOOTNOTE}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Moral of the story

Don't use `setspace` with `beamer`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I generally don't use setspace in beamer. My main problem is the space between lines of \tableofcontents are shrunk, if I put \toc in a minipage or column. That leads to all this fuss.

Comment: @BaRud Use `\linespread{1.5}\selectfont` in the frame where you want bigger interline skip.

Comment: Ah...thats the easiest one....I had did \linespread, but I was not aware of \selectfont. \linspread{}\selectfont did it for me