# Tiny, tightly spaced, unnumbered footnotes in beamer presentation (possibly with columns)

Tags: beamer, footnotes, line-spacing

For reasons outside my control, I need to put tiny, tightly spaced, and unnumbered footnotes in a beamer frame. The frame possibly contains columns, in which case the footnotes should be at the bottom of the frame instead of that of the column.

I have tried various ways to achieve this (please see the MWE) but none of them works out: 1) the footnote numbering is still there; 2) the spacing between the footnotes is too large; 3) the footnote still appears inside the column sometimes.

How can I make tiny, tightly spaced, unnumbered footnotes at the bottom of a beamer frame (possibly with columns)?

If all of this is too much to ask of the footnote command of beamer, any suggestion that does not use the internal footnote command of beamer but use another method to produce something similar to a footnote that achieves the desired look is welcome as well.

MWE:

[image: footnote MWE]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%make footnotes font tiny
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}

% intended to hide footnote numbering - does not work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30726/9789
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
    \endgroup
} 

%intended to tighten footnote spacing - does not work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118005/9789
\usepackage{setspace}
\setbeamertemplate{footnote}%
{%
    \parindent 1em\noindent%
    \raggedright\setstretch{1}%
    \hbox to 1.8em{\hfil\insertfootnotemark}\insertfootnotetext\par%
} 

\begin{document}

\frame{
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item some content\blfootnote[frame]{my unnumbered, tiny, tightly spaced footnote}
                \item some more content\blfootnote[frame]{second unnumbered, tiny, tightly spaced footnote}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item some more content\footnote[frame]{third tiny, tightly spaced footnote}
                \item some more content\footnote[frame]{fourth tiny, tightly spaced footnote}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you passing `[frame]` as an optional argument to your `blfootnote` command, which is defined without optional arguments? Even for normal footnotes it is unnecessary because it is the default behaviour.

Comment: Please have a look at the answers to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455917/how-to-remove-footnote-marker-number-in-beamer

Comment: @samcarter The `[frame]` option is supposed to put the footnote at the bottom of the frame instead of that of the column. Please see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86757/9789).

Comment: But your `blfootnote` does not support optional arguments, you would need another definition. Anyway as you want unnumbered notes, I would use `\footnotetext` like in the answers to the question I linked to.

Comment: @samcarter Thank you for the link; I read that question earlier and part of my MWE comes from that question (with link there). The issue with `\footnotetext` is 1) it appears at the bottom of the column instead of the frame; 2) it seems that with animation (`\uncover`, etc.), the `footnotetext` may not appear.

Comment: `footnotetext` is to be used outside the column environment

Comment: It can be adjusted on which overlay it appears. When do you want it to appear?

Comment: @samcarter Ideally simultaneous with the relevant text. But for example, how do I make it appear on all slides?

Comment: `\footnotetext{text}` will be shown on all slides per default

Comment: If you only want it on the second, `\footnotetext<2>{text}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84717/discussion-between-fang-jing-and-samcarter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-using the idea from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455981/36296 I would do the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}

\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
  \parindent 1em\noindent%
  \raggedright
  \linespread{0.5}
  \hbox to 1.8em{\hfil\insertfootnotemark}\insertfootnotetext\par\vspace*{-0.2em}%
}

\defbeamertemplate{footnote}{unnumbered}{%
  \parindent 1em\noindent%
  \raggedright
    \hbox to 1.8em{\hfil}\insertfootnotetext\par\vspace*{-0.2em}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begingroup
        \setbeamertemplate{footnote}[unnumbered]
        \footnotetext{my unnumbered, tiny, tightly spaced footnote tiny, tightly spaced footnote tiny, tightly spaced footnote tiny, tightly spaced footnote tiny, tightly spaced footnote tiny, tightly spaced footnotetiny, tightly spaced footnote tiny, tightly spaced footnote tiny, tightly spaced footnote}
      \footnotetext{second unnumbered, tiny, tightly spaced footnote}
    \endgroup

    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item some content
                \item some more content
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item some more content\footnote[frame]{third tiny, tightly spaced footnote}
                \item some more content\footnote[frame]{fourth tiny, tightly spaced footnote}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one followup question: It seems that when I load the `setspace` package the unnumbered footnotes as defined above disappears. Why is that the case? Is there a workaround?

Comment: @FangJing Don't use `setspace` with beamer

Comment: @FangJing For explanation see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235024/36296