# How to get \footnote and \footfullcite to work in Fibeamer Beamer theme?

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footnotes

I am using Fibeamer beamer theme(can be accessed [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/fibeamer-for-the-faculty-of-sports-studies-at-the-masaryk-university-in-brno/qpqhgjbmwyng)
The `\footnote` and `\footfullcite` commands don't produce any output. However the references are properly rendered with a frame showing `\printbibliography`. I suspect this has to do with the footer definition in the theme's style file. However I m unable to get this to work.

Here's a MWE

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[microtype,faculty=fsps]{fibeamer}
\usepackage[style=numeric,doi=false,url=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\author{Karthik}
\title{Presentation title}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\begin{frame}{ First slide }
    Testing citations \footfullcite{Smith2012}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On page 9 of the [`fibeamer` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer-contrib/themes/fibeamer/fibeamer.pdf) we find

> `setspace` - This package is used to adjust the leading to 115 %. Loading
>   this package breaks any top-level footnotes without the `[frame]` optional
>   parameter specified. [This is a known bug.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118005/35864)

So while `\footnote{foo}` does not work, `\footnote[frame]{bar}` does. We now need to tell `biblatex` to insert `[frame]` whenever it calls footnotes. This can be done with

```
\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd{\blx@mkbibfootnote}[2]{%
  \iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\blx@warning{Nested notes}%
     \addspace\mkbibparens{#2}}
    {\unspace
     \csuse{footnote#1}[frame]{\protecting{\blxmkbibnote{foot}{#2}}}}}
\makeatother
```