# Using biblatex \textcite and columns in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex

Using `\textcite` with biblatex in beamer it creates a footnote with the citation, that appears at the end of the slide. Using it with columns, the footnote stays inside the column, breaking the layout. If I use it in blocks, it stays inside the block, with the same problem.

How should biblatex be used in beamer to obtain a good result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is solved by using the `[frame]` option for `\footnote`, you can redefine the internal command calling footnotes in `biblatex` to do that for you automatically.

```
\documentclass[british]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd{\blx@mkbibfootnote}[2]{%
  \iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\blx@warning{Nested notes}%
     \addspace\mkbibparens{#2}}
    {\unspace
     \ifnum\blx@notetype=\tw@
       \expandafter\@firstoftwo
     \else
       \expandafter\@secondoftwo
     \fi
       {\csuse{blx@theendnote#1}{\protecting{\blxmkbibnote{end}{#2}}}}
       {\csuse{footnote#1}[frame]{\protecting{\blxmkbibnote{foot}{#2}}}}}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      Lorem \textcite{sigfridsson}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      ipsum \textcite{nussbaum}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{Dolor}
    dolor \textcite{worman}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two columns with frame footnotes.]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/395161/35864

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to how footnotes are managed by beamer. A workaround I found to solve this problem is to define this command:

> \newcommand{\citef}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}\footnote[frame]{\fullcite{#1}}}

And then use `\citef{key}` instead of `\textcite{key}`. It is not maybe the most elegant solution, but it works.